# How can I help?

Tags: discussion, help

I am very new to Stack Overflow, but I want to help on the Mathematics site. The problem is that I'm not particularly smart enough to answer the majority of questions.

How should I help?

I'm decent at math, but some of the concepts still elude me.

Comment: [How does a new user get started on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252149/4642212), [I want to help and answer questions, but I can't find questions to answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268157/4642212).

Answer (score 8):

### To help other people:

You can answer questions you understand. Please don't try to answer questions that are above your skill level. It becomes quite obvious to everyone else if you do.

If you are not sure where to get started, check out this post: [How does a new user get started on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252149/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-stack-overflow) which mentions watching tags on subjects you are interested in or knowledgeable.

You can also always direct users asking questions to resources (such as an article or book) even if you are unsure of the exact answer, but you know where the answer could be.

### To help the site:

If you want to help the site itself, not just other people, here are the basic 10 things you can do (not ordered by importance). You can:

1. [Ask](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) good questions.
2. [Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) good questions (especially ones with little or no answers).
3. Improve questions and answers through [editing](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/editing).
4. [Flag](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) inappropriate material.
5. Take the [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour).
6. Go through the [help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help).
7. Participate in the site's [meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/).
8. Promote the site online.
9. Participate in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=math.stackexchange.com).
10. And most important of all, be a good user! Being nice and respectful to others is essential. Make sure to follow the [code of conduct](https://math.stackexchange.com/conduct).

As an added benefit, doing 3, 4, 5, 6, and 10 makes our infinitely valued moderators' lives easier.